# Newtonsoft.Json - ignore DataContractAttribute

Tags: c#, json.net

i have a type

```
 class Foo 
 {
   public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

and i can serialize it quickly with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method (without custom settings). But if i decorate class definition with `[DataContract]` property Name is not serialized.

Is there a way to serialize `DataContract` `Foo` type WITHOUT decorating it with additional `Newtonsoft.Json` specific attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try annotating the property with the [DataMember Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
class Foo 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```